# Visual Studio using existing Xamarin project repository

Tags: xamarin, compatibility, versions

I'm very new to Xamarin, and running into some problems. My colleague and I are running VS 2017 Community and I'm simply trying to run their project on my computer, but having some problems. First, I try to open the app with **File->open->Project/Solution**, navigate to the .sln file and I get:

```
"The version of the selected solution is higher than the solution version 
supported by this Visual Studio release. Please try downloading the latest 
service pack for this Visual Studio release, or opening in a more recent 
version of Visual Studio, if available."
```

But I have VS Community 2017, Version 15.2, which what I've found so far is the most up to date.

Any ideas? I can post any logs necessary if any are generated giving more info about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the `.sln` file from `"Format Version 15.00"` to `"Format Version 12.00"` and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to open a solution created on a Mac using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition in VS 2017 on Windows.

I managed to load the project though by opening the .csproj file instead.